# Where is `pg_temp` documented in the PG manual?

Tags: postgresql, temporary-tables

I have tried various ways to search for `pg_temp` in the manual, but could not find it. Is it documented in the manual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is documented at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html

> Likewise, the current session's temporary-table schema, pg_temp_nnn, is always searched if it exists. It can be explicitly listed in the path by using the alias pg_temp. If it is not listed in the path then it is searched first (even before pg_catalog). However, the temporary schema is only searched for relation (table, view, sequence, etc) and data type names. It is never searched for function or operator names.

Comment: Thanks. It's embarrassing that I've read that section before and overlooked it. Oh well.